# String value won't return

Tags: java, string, methods, return

It was working fine with only Class A and B, but when i added Class C, it will not return the value "Hello" anymore.

Class A:

```
public void firstName() {
       Deco dec = new Deco();
       x=dec.first;
       System.out.println("value: "+x);
```

Class B (Deco class):

```
public String firstOne(byte[] b) throws Exception {
     if(xxx.equals(y)){
           String first="Hello";
       return(first);

     }else{
           System.out.println("Error");
     }
```

Class C:

```
public String test(String path, String name) {
     decode = decode_text(get_byte_data(image));
     Deco dec = new Deco();
 dec.firstOne(decode);

}
```

Comment: What programming language?

Comment: What is `xxx`? Anything else missing you should include?

Comment: Looks like `C#` - please confirm and tag the question.

Comment: Sorry, i didn't make it clear.
It is Java language.
xxx and y are two Strings, such as (xxx=19b3e2ae, y=19b3e2ae)

Comment: This shouldn't even compile, `firstOne` has an execution branch that does not return a `String`.

Comment: Why firstOne didn't return a String, this is the problem i got, because in the method firstName didn't get value x.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Class C (or should I say method C) doesn't look like it returns anything, maybe something like this:

```
    public String test(String path, String name) {
 decode = decode_text(get_byte_data(image));
 Deco dec = new Deco();
 return dec.firstOne(decode);

 }
```

Comment: I forgot to put the `return` when i posted. 
method of `firstOne` didn't return a String to method of `firstName`.